# Ran update statement to update some column values and need to rollback

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have an update statement to update some values for a table, but made a mistake. How can I roll this back?

The query I ran is this:

```
update t1
set t1.[DateAdded] = case 
                         when t1.[DateAdded] is null
                             then cast(getdate() as date) 
                     end
from [PEA].[pc].[TPC_Participants_Record_STG] as t1;
go
```

Comment: You can roll it back by making sure your connection doesn't have autocommit on, and using the `rollback` command instead of `commit`.  If autocommit is on, you're stuck with trying to fix it.  Don't do prod updates with autocommit on.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to try and fix it as autocommit is on.

Answer (score 2):

You *might* get away with the following update:

```sql
UPDATE [PEA].[pc].[TPC_Participants_Record_STG]
SET DateAdded = NULL
WHERE DateAdded = CAST(GETDATE() AS date);
```

But note carefully that the above assumes that before your erroneous update no records already had a `DateAdded` value with today's date.  If not, then the above would be nulling out some possibly valid data which should not change.

Comment: Everything in the [DateAdded] column is now NULL. Is there a way I can restore the databack for this one table without restoring the entire database?

Comment: Always run the where clause of your update as a select first and make sure it's only returning the records you actually want to update.